# C# WPF - TransitioningContentControl with App.content

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, user-controls, mahapps.metro

I Work with the theme of MahApps (Metro Dark) I looked the animations of this theme.

I came to a dead end: indeed I created a system to switch between different UserControl, that is to say that I have only one window and clicking on different buttons, I have this or such UserControl. But now I am with this system switch, I have no animation (only the start of the application).

How can I make an animation for each change in UserControl (Keeping Metro theme)?

Somebody ask me : use TransitioningContentControl

But i made my switcher like this :

```
class Switcher
{
    public static UserControl WClient;
    public static UserControl WHome;
    public static UserControl WDataBase;

    public Switcher()
    {
        WClient = new Windows.Client();
        WHome = new Windows.Home();
        WDataBase = new Windows.DataBase();
    }

    public static void currentWindow(UserControl window, string color)
    {

        Window curApp = Application.Current.MainWindow;
        curApp.Content = window;

        if (window == WClient)
        {
            curApp.Title = "CLIENT - INFO-TOOLS - BY NAOGRAFIX";
        }
        else if (window == WDataBase)
        {
            curApp.Title = "DATABASE - INFO-TOOLS - BY NAOGRAFIX";
        }
        else
        {
            curApp.Title = "HOME - INFO-TOOLS - BY NAOGRAFIX";
        }

        currentColor(color); 
  }
```

}

Now, when i clic on a button (to switch userControl) i use this :

```
private void BtnDataBase_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     var color = "Red";

     if (DataBase.isConnected) { color = "Green"; }
     Switcher.currentWindow(Switcher.WDataBase, color);
}
```

I use CONTENT, i dont know if i can use TransitioningContentControl

Help :)

Nao*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do need to use transitioning content control as you have said. You can add that as the direct content of the window then access it by name from the mainwindow and change its content instead.

Xaml

```
<metro:TransitioningContentControl x:Name="tContent"/>
```

C#

```
((ContentControl)curApp.FindName("tContent")).Content = window;
```

You will need the xml namespace definition

```
xmlns:metro="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
```

and you can change the transition using the Transition property on TransitioningContentControl

Answer (score 1):

WPF XAML below shows use of MahApps.Metro TransitioningContentControl.

Click on the Content listbox to switch content.

Select the transition effect in the Transition listbox, then change selected Content to see the effect.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfMahApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:mah="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <TextBlock x:Key="Content1" Width="400" Height="200" Text="Content 1: TextBox" Background="Aqua" />
        <Canvas x:Key="Content2" Width="200" Height="400" Background="DarkOrange">
            <Ellipse Fill="YellowGreen" Stroke="Black"  Width="100" Height="200" />
            <Label Content="Content2: Canvas" />
        </Canvas>
        <Border x:Key="Content3" Width="100" Height="100" Background="Yellow" BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="4">
            <TextBlock Text="Content3: Border" />
        </Border>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
            <CheckBox Margin="4" Content="Is Transitioning" IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=TransitioningContentControl,Path=IsTransitioning , Mode=OneWay}" />
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="8">
                <TextBlock Text="Content" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                <ListBox Name="ContentSelection" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    <ListBoxItem Content="Content 1" Tag="{StaticResource Content1}" />
                    <ListBoxItem Content="Content 2" Tag="{StaticResource Content2}" />
                    <ListBoxItem Content="Content 3" Tag="{StaticResource Content3}" />
                </ListBox>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="8">
                <TextBlock Text="Transition" FontWeight="Bold" />
                <ListBox Name="Transition" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    <ListBoxItem Content="Default" Tag="{x:Static mah:TransitionType.Default}"/>
                    <ListBoxItem Content="Normal" Tag="{x:Static mah:TransitionType.Normal}"/>
                    <ListBoxItem Content="Up" Tag="{x:Static mah:TransitionType.Up}"/>
                    <ListBoxItem Content="Down" Tag="{x:Static mah:TransitionType.Down}"/>
                    <ListBoxItem Content="Left" Tag="{x:Static mah:TransitionType.Left}" />
                    <ListBoxItem Content="Right" Tag="{x:Static mah:TransitionType.Right}"/>
                    <ListBoxItem Content="LeftReplace" Tag="{x:Static mah:TransitionType.LeftReplace}"/>
                    <ListBoxItem Content="RightReplace" Tag="{x:Static mah:TransitionType.RightReplace}"/>
                </ListBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
        <mah:TransitioningContentControl Margin="8" 
            Name="TransitioningContentControl"
            Background="Beige" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1"
            Content="{Binding ElementName=ContentSelection, Path=SelectedValue.Tag}" 
            Transition="{Binding ElementName=Transition, Path=SelectedValue.Tag}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

[image: MAHApps Demo]

Comment: @djack109 : The cs code is auto-generated for you by Visual Studio when you do Add > New Item > Visual C# > WPF > Window (WPF). You can then paste the XAML code from the answer. You also need to add reference to nuget package MahApps.Metro.

Comment: Oh right, you don't have any c# in the code-behind? Ah yes I can see whats happening :)